# Fancybox navigation and close buttons blinking between images

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Every next and back button click causes the three buttons to blink. I believe the fade effect is being applied to them when it should only be applied to the images.

Here is a page with the issue for reference, the enlarged images have the issue
https://jessiesrugs.com/persian-rugs/1393-persian-oriental-rug-3-5-x-5-1-beige-hamedan.html

I've confirmed this by setting `nextEffect:"none"` in *jquery.fancybox.js* which stops the buttons from blinking, but I still want the images to fade. How can I only stop the buttons from blinking?

Comment: Well, this is how fancyBox v2 works. Is there any particular reason you are not upgrading to v3?

Comment: I wish that I could, v3 causes issues in mobile. v2 is perfect except for the blinking.

Comment: What kind of issues are you experiencing?